# Microsoft 365 on Primary Domain, Send Notifications on Subdomain

Tags: dns, spf, microsoft365

I have my primary mail service on my BlueHost domain as Microsoft 365. I want to have notifications go out from a subdomain via the internal BlueHost service. NameCheap is the registrar, so I'm doing all my DNS entries on NameCheap. So far, I've got this

```
A        @    [My IPv4 Address]
CNAME    www  [my-domain].com
TXT      @    v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
MX       @    [my-domain]-com.mail.protection.outlook.com.    0
```

Now I want my notifications emails to send from do_not_reply@notification.[my-domain].com, without interrupting service on my M365 mailbox. I have an MX on it for now to catch bounces, but what do I do to have it included in the SPF?

```
MX       notification    [my-domain].com    15
```

Right now, Google is rejecting the emails sent from the notification.[my-domain].com box. The site I'm trying to send notifications from is at a different subdomain of the same primary domain name, if that's relevant. I've browsed similar articles here, but haven't seemed to find a solution that works. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create an SPF-record on sub-domain level with only the server you send the notifications from.

```
TXT notifications "v=spf1 ip4:0.0.0.0 -all"
MX notifications 0 contoso.com
```

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. My project was interrupted. Back at it now.

I tried the above and interesting behavior resulted:
- Using the FluentSMTP plugin in WordPress for back end notifications from abc@notifications.contoso.com, I can send to any domain EXCEPT contoso.com. When I send a test message to someone@contoso.com it says that no such mailbox exists. Of course I've confirmed that it does, and I'm using real values instead of these test values.

- Also, the mail still goes to junk folders, despite having SPF records in place.

Thanks for any further help.

Comment: The behaviour is as expected. Since you configured `notification.contoso.com`. For the NDR, can it be that the service you're sending email from has an internal DNS-server?